# Neo4j optional match is NOT really equivalent to an SQL outer join

Tags: neo4j, outer-join

I would like to return all rows in one set, only some of which have a relationship to another set. For example, here are my nodes:

```
CREATE (n1:Union{UID:1}) 
CREATE (n2:Union{UID:2}) 
CREATE (n3:Union{UID:3}) 
CREATE (n4:Union{UID:4}) 
CREATE (n5:Union{UID:5}) 

CREATE (p1:Person{RN:1}) 
CREATE (p2:Person{RN:2}) 
CREATE (p3:Person{RN:3}) 
CREATE (p4:Person{RN:4}) 
CREATE (p5:Person{RN:5})
```

and relationships

```
match (a:Union{UID:1}),(b:Person{RN:1})
create (a)-[:Child]->(b)

match (c:Union{UID:1}),(d:Person{RN:2})
create (c)-[:Child]->(d)

match (e:Union{UID:5}),(f:Person{RN:5})
create (e)-[:Child]->(f)
```

When I run this query

```
optional match (u:Union)-[:Child*0..1]->(c:Person) 
with u.UID as UID,case when c is not NULL then collect(c.RN) else NULL end as child
return UID,child order by UID
```

the result is

```
UID child
1   [1, 2]
5   [5]
```

What I am looking for is

```
UID  Child
1    [1,2]
2    NULL
3    NULL
4    NULL
5    [5]
```

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you did an OPTIONAL MATCH on the entire pattern, and expecting it to behave the way you want isn't correct (and would be incredibly inefficient, as it would have to match to all nodes of both sides). You need to match on the node you want to be there regardless, then optional match on the rest:

```
match (u:Union)
optional match (u)-[:Child*0..1]->(c:Person) 
with u, collect(c.RN) as child
return u.UID as UID, case when size(child) = 0 then null else child end 
order by UID
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what was desired.